# Correct design for a single-page web app using Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

The single-page web app has the following requirements...
1. Contain 3 items on the page: date chooser, grid type chooser, and the grid itself (will use jqGrid)
2. When date chooser or grid type chooser is changed the grid must change appropriately
3. The state is persisted between sessions, for example, today I chose the Traffic Sources grid for 9/07/2013 and logged off, tomorrow I log in and see the same state

Here's a design that I'm thinking:
In html put 3 divs for each of the items: date chooser, grid type chooser, and the grid. Tie each item to a corresponding view. Make a Model, StateItem, extend 2 Models from it, DateStateItem and GridTypeStateItem. Make a Backbone.js Collection, StateItems, that consists of Models of type StateItems. Register the DateStateItem model with the DateChooserView and GridTypeStateItem model with GridTypeView and the Collection that consists of these 2 models with the GridView. This way the GridView can listen to any StateItem change that the Collection consists of and render the jqGrid appropriately.

Please let me know if this is a correct application of the Backbone.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about a lot of different aspects of the program's design, some of which have nothing to do with Backbone.  Backbone provides the ability to create a Model View Controller architecture.

The first paragraph really has little to do with Backbone as it appears to be about UI and cookies/sessions.

The second paragraph has more to with the architecture.

Some good reading for getting started with Backbone can be found here:

http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/11/backbone-dot-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started/

http://backbonetutorials.com/

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/